# Java on windows 10 mobile

Tags: java, windows, mobile, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I thought Windows 10 would be same on desktop and mobile phones, but now I read that there is a "Windows 10 Mobile".

My purpose is to get the mobile phone, running with Windows 10 mobile, execute Java. I tested some things in Visual Studio with the emulator but the mobile-OS on the phone doesn't open any exe- or jar-files .

Has anyone got an idea how to handle this?

Is there a possibility to integrate Java with a Windows app? 
Should I ask the phone-manufacturer whether a Java-implementation exists?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 mobile and windows phone does not support java.  You can use C# or VB.net with XAML or HTML 5 with js.  I know this has been suggested in the user voice site if you want to vote for it

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/6158738-java-sdk-to-develop-windows-phone-apps